# How to Strip First Character From String in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a word, " Unassigned" where the first character is a hidden character we use to alphabetically sort a list. How can we remove this character using XAML? Here is how we currently remove it:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="Ј Unassigned">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
            <Expander IsExpanded="True" Style="{StaticResource ExpanderBase}">
               <Expander.Header>
                  <TextBlock FontSize="18" FontStyle="Italic">
                     <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}">
                           <Binding Path="Name[2]"/>
                           <Binding Path="Name[3]"/>
                           <Binding Path="Name[4]"/>
                           <Binding Path="Name[5]"/>
                           <Binding Path="Name[6]"/>
                           <Binding Path="Name[7]"/>
                           <Binding Path="Name[8]"/>
                           <Binding Path="Name[9]"/>
                           <Binding Path="Name[10]"/>
                           <Binding Path="Name[11]"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                     </TextBlock.Text>
                  </TextBlock>
               </Expander.Header>
               <ItemsPresenter/>
            </Expander>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```

When this is run, it converts the "Ј Unassigned" to "Unassigned".

Is there any way to do this in XAML or must it be done using a C# converter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think that there is a XAML-only way to this, but using a value converter would be good solution to this. It is much more flexible than your multi-binding example, as it allows for variable length of the bound `string`. If this is used often, you could turn it into a separate markup extension.

```
public class RemoveHiddenCharacterConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      if (value == null)
         return null;

      var text = ((string)value);
      return text.Length < 2 ? string.Empty : text.Substring(2);
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
   }
}
```

You have to create an instance of this converter in a `ResourceDictionary`, then you can use it like this.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource RemoveHiddenCharacterConverter}}"/>
```

Another option is of course to rethink the concept of the character prefix and solve that problem in another way, instead of working around it, if you do not depend on it.